# Pass delete swipe gesture from UIPageViewController to UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIPageViewController` and swipe events don't seem to be passing to the `UITableView`.

I was able to disable bouncing of edges for my `UIPageViewController`, but I still haven't found a way to consistently enable swiping to delete in my `UITableView`.

[image: In this sample, it takes multiple swipes to get the delete button to show up. The gesture is extremely finicky on an actual device]

In this sample, it takes multiple swipes to get the delete button to show up. The gesture is extremely finicky on an actual device

There isn't another page after the page on the right, so there's no reason for the `UIPageViewController` to need that swipe.

In `viewDidLoad` I have:

```
for view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews {
    if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Below that I have:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    print(gestureRecognizer)
    if gestureRecognizer is UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
}
```

There are a lot of related posts with different answers, but none of them work for my use case.

Comment: This is more of an alternative than a solution to my question, but I just used MGSwipeTableCell. It was very easy to implement. https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the swipe of the UIPageViewController by **not** using `datasource`, just use `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion` method to provide the contents.Hope the swipe of the tableView can work.

Comment: I have to display multiple pages, so I'm not sure how I could implement this without completely tearing apart the `UIPageViewController`